# How can i retrieve a list of users from a sharepoint group via CSOM where users displayname start with?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

i have a problem with retrieving users from a sharepoint group via CSOM C#. I am currently retrieving all users via CSOM with my code below

```
    public List<SPUser> GetGroupMembers(string groupName)
    {
        var appContext = _sharePointService.AppContext;
        Group group = appContext.Web.SiteGroups.GetByName(groupName);

        appContext.Load(group, grp => grp.Title, grp => grp.Users);
        appContext.ExecuteQuery();

        List<ClientResult<PrincipalInfo>> principalsResults = new List<ClientResult<PrincipalInfo>>();
        foreach (var user in group.Users)
        {
            principalsResults.Add(Utility.ResolvePrincipal(appContext, appContext.Web, user.LoginName, PrincipalType.User, PrincipalSource.All, null, false));
        }
        appContext.ExecuteQuery();

        List<SPUser> spUsers = new List<SPUser>();
        foreach (var principalResult in principalsResults)
        {
            spUsers.Add(_spPrincipalFactory.Get(principalResult.Value));
        }

        return spUsers.OrderBy(u => u.Name).ToList();
    }
```

But i only want users where displayname starts with "Mark*". Is this possible? How could i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use linq to filter.

```
spUsers = spUsers.Where(itm => itm.Name.Trim().ToUpper().StartsWith("MARK")).ToList();
```

This will return only the user whose name starts with "Mark". Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. But in this i have to retrieve all users fromthe group first into memory and then do the linq query on this object. But i want to prevent this and get only the users from the sp group which start with "mark*" so that i need to retrieve only lets say 5 users instead of 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can get like this.

```
 using (context = new ClientContext("SiteUrl"))
            {
                foreach (char c in "Password") securePassword.AppendChar(c);
                context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("user@domain.onmicrosoft.com", securePassword);
                context.Load(context.Web, w => w.ServerRelativeUrl, w => w.Url);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Group group = context.Web.SiteGroups.GetByName("GroupName");
                context.Load(group, grp => grp.Title, grp => grp.Users);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                List<User> lstUser = new List<User>();
                lstUser = group.Users.Where(itm => itm.Title.Trim().ToUpper().StartsWith("TEST")).ToList();
            }
```

Try it and let me know.

Comment: Thanks, but wohn't this line load always all users  `context.Load(group, grp => grp.Title, grp => grp.Users);`